# connect and access Function in Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web service from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, soap, microsoft-dynamics, navision, node-soap

I am new to SOAP we services and recently got task to consume existing NAV service from Node.js. My Node.js code is on Google cloud functions.

So far I tried really hard using this answer: [Is it possible to access Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web service from NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100858/is-it-possible-to-access-microsoft-dynamics-nav-web-service-from-nodejs)

But it seems like I am not able to get any response except 'Nan'.

what should be my values for wsdl_headder and wsdl_option?

this is my request, REQUESTXML =

```
<GETDETAIL LanguageCode="ENG" ID="1042" TNo="T00205" TaxBreakdown="TRUE">

  <SUBHEADERS>
    <SUBHEADER Name="SALES"/>
  </SUBHEADERS>
</GETDETAIL>
```

and this is what we call in OLD JAVA code,
xmlCommunicationPort.getdetail(REQUESTXML, returnString);

xmlCommunicationPort is the object created in during Authentication and getdetail is a method generated automatically by a java.

Comment: Have you tried it with postman or soapUI?

Comment: Yes, But still wasn't able to qquery the SOAP or maintain the connection. In the end I ended up bypassing the SOAP services, but would still like to understand how it work properly.