# Authenticating to Dynamics NAV for OData

Tags: node.js, web-services, dynamics-nav

I'm trying to write a node.js script that uses a Dynamics NAV Odata feed.

I have both a UserAccount/PW and a Web Services Access Key from my Dynamics NAV setup.

I can't for the life of my find out how to properly authenticate, either by adding something in a header or by adding something in the URL query. I've tried using the 'username:password@server' format. I've tried encoding that as base64 and adding that in the Header for the 'Authentication' value.

The [documentation itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj551746(v=nav.90).aspx) is incredibly non-specific. I know how to generate the key, but I don't know how to properly send that key to NAV to authenticate.

I'm using the 'request-promise' npm package, which takes an 'options' argument that I can add arbitrary header key:value pairs into. Please someone give me some direction about how to authenticate to NAV. I've been on this for hours.

Comment: Here is a full example on how to authenticate in node.js using NTLM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823338/10030693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a satisfactory answer.

Using [node-libcurl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libcurl) I was able to cURL to a url using the format

`http://username:password@<server>/ODATA_table`

specifically my cURL module looks like this:

```
var Curl = require('node-libcurl').Curl;

var curl = new Curl(),
    close = curl.close.bind(curl);

function getOData(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        curl.setOpt(Curl.option.URL, url);
        curl.setOpt(Curl.option.HTTPAUTH, Curl.auth.NTLM);
        curl.setOpt(Curl.option.SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl.setOpt(Curl.option.SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl.setOpt(Curl.option.POST, 0);


        curl.on('end', function (statusCode, body, headers) {

            var retObj = JSON.parse(body);
            resolve(retObj);
            close();
        });

        curl.on( 'error', function(e){
            reject(e);
            close();
        });

        curl.perform();
    })
}

module.exports = {getOData: getOData};
```

But I have to explicitly ask for json in the url, like `?format=json`.

Comment: Remember to close the handle even if the request was successful.

Comment: You can also do like what this guide says: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823338/10030693

Answer (score -1):

Tkol, you're right,also you can use [guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), it's very simple, that's a sample function that query customers table :

```
public function ReadCustomer($identifier=0)
{
  try {

       $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();

       $apiRequest = $client->request('GET', 'http://server:port/ServiceName/WS/CompanyName/Page/Customer?$filter=No eq \''.$identifier.'\'',[
            'auth' =>'username','password', 'NTLM' ],       //NTLM authentication required
            'debug' => true                                  //If needed to debug   
      ]);


      $content = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody()->getContents());
      return $content;

  } catch (RequestException $re) {
      //For handling exception
  }
}
```

you can check my sample:
[update/delete/get from Dynamics NAV OData webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618045/how-to-delete-records-using-odata-dynamics-nav-2017-web-services/47733880#47733880)

Comment: Ok, sorry for my inexperience in answering, I'll eliminate it, tanks

Comment: Another example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823338/10030693