# How to Delete records using Odata Dynamics NAV 2017 web services

Tags: web-services, odata, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

I was developed a php application that connects to Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2017 OData Web Services, I can read (GET), and create (POST) with no problems,but for delete I receive the error 405, Microsoft say that it is possible to delete :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd355398(v=nav.90).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn182582(v=nav.90).aspx

I check the page in Dynamics NAV that have a correct property  InsertAllowed, ModifyAllowed, or DeleteAllowed, is set to Yes, and I have permissions to delete

After try with postman recevie the same error:

[image: Delete Error Odata debug with postman]

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution!! , I write myself to help another who is with the same problem:

You only have to add the identifier on the request url, in my case the identifier of the customer table (**'/Customer(No='.$identifier.')'**)

This is a sample code in PHP with guzzle and table customer of Dynamics NAV:

```
 $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
 $uri=env('HTTP_URIBASE', '');
 $apiRequest = $client->request('DELETE', $uri.'/Customer(No='.$identifier.')',[
        'auth' => [env('HTTP_USERNAME', 'usuari'),env('HTTP_PASSWORD', ''), 'ntlm' ],
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
                       'Accept' => 'application/json']
  ]);
  $content = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody()->getContents());
```

for updates (**PATCH**) I have to first read the **etag** of the reccord (**@odata.etag**), and add on the headers (**If-Match** value) for update:

```
 $client = new GuzzleHttpClient();
 $uri=env('HTTP_URIBASE', '');
 // get the recordset of the customer
 $apiRequest = $client->request('GET', $uri.'/Customer(No='.$identifier.')',[
            'auth' => [env('HTTP_USERNAME', 'usuari'),env('HTTP_PASSWORD', ''), 'ntlm' ]     
            ]);
 $content = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody()->getContents());
 $etag= $content->{'@odata.etag'};

 // update description of the customer
 $apiRequest = $client->request('PATCH', $uri.'/Customer(No='.$identifier.')',[
        'auth' => [env('HTTP_USERNAME', 'usuari'),env('HTTP_PASSWORD', ''), 'ntlm' ],
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
                       'Accept' => 'application/json',
                       'If-Match' =>$etag ],
        'body'    => '{"Name":"'.$missatge.'"}' 
         ]);
 $content = json_decode($apiRequest->getBody()->getContents());
```

Comment: Hi colo, I want to expose oData for a database using PHP but I havent been able to find much/updated information, did you use a framework? or you write it yourself? will be possible for you to send me some guide on how to build this? thank you

Comment: Hi Manza, yes, I use a framework Laravel in my case, You can see my sample on my web page :http://www.colome.org/laravel-custom-authentication-microsoft-dynamics-nav/